# Draw a circle in an Emgu ConvolutionKernelF

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I want to convolute my image with a kernel that has the shape of a circle (not filled) using Emgu.
I found the ConvolutionKernelF which suits my needs ([Gaussian Noise in emgucv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782941/gaussian-noise-in-emgucv/7812901#7812901)).

Does anybody know how I could draw a circle in this kernel? Without anti-aliasing that is.
Another simple method do do a convolution with a circular kernel is also appreciated.

I tried this:

```
Image<Gray, float> kernel = new Image<Gray, float>(radius * 2 + 1, radius * 2 + 1);
kernel.Draw(new CircleF(new Point(radius, radius), radius), new Gray(1.0), 1);
ConvolutionKernelF ckernel = new ConvolutionKernelF(kernel.Data); // error
kernel.CopyTo(ckernel);
```

Unfortunatly, the third statement gives me:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float[*,*,*]' to 'float[*,*]'
```

In addition, it does'nt seem very efficient.

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it like this:

```
Image<Gray, float> kernel = new Image<Gray, float>(radius * 2 + 1, radius * 2 + 1);
kernel.Draw(new CircleF(new Point(radius, radius), radius), new Gray(1.0), 1);
CvInvoke.cvFilter2D(A, B, kernel, new Point(-1, -1));
```