# How can I generate a standard normal random variable in F# (or .Net in general)?

Tags: .net, random, f#, gaussian

I need standard normal (Gaussian) random variables for my simulation. What is the easiest way to generate them? Unlike in java, the standard [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class seems to cater for only uniform variables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MathNet.Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) library works well with F# and provides various random generators as well as different probability distribution with random sampling methods. Some more details on how to apply random sampling from probability distributions can be found [here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Probability.html).