# C# library that has normrnd function from MATLAB

Tags: c#, matlab

Is there any library in c# that contains the normrnd function in MATLAB and works the same way?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: This code project article could help you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25172/Simple-Random-Number-Generation

Comment: in case you need just a quick and dirty gaussian: Math.Pow(Math.E, -Math.Pow((Random.nextDouble()-mu)/sigma, 2))/ (sigma*Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random Gaussian Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a library do this *exactly* but I want to say something.

In .NET, there is a [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class which does;

> Represents a pseudo-random number generator, a device that produces a
>   sequence of numbers that meet certain statistical requirements for
>   randomness.

For *distribution* part, there is an article which I think you must look.

- [`.NET random number generators and distributions`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15102/NET-random-number-generators-and-distributions)
- Check also [`Simple Random Number Generation`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25172/Simple-Random-Number-Generation)