# Use of 2D Gaussian Function to map heights in 3D environment

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d

I'm creating a project in a city environment. I want to distribute the buildings using Gaussian distribution so that the heights of the buildings are distributed around the centre (mean). In the same nature to the image below.

[2D Gaussian distribution image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3e/Gaussian_2d.svg/512px-Gaussian_2d.svg.png)

Using the equation on the Gaussian Wikipedia page, I came up with some code but I'm not sure how I'd implement it to achieve what I have mentioned above and whether my code is correct so far.

[Current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8cl3.png)

Comment: What is your specific technical challenge ? What have you tried and how has it not given you the expected answer ?

Comment: The technical challenge is how to use the 2D to enable me to map the heights. As you can see I outputted them to the console currently. However, I'm not sure if that implementation is correct mathematically and whether this is the correct approach.

Comment: What is your experience of Unity3D and/or DirectX height map implementations ? The SO site really is best used for solving specific technical questions - its not really a forum for techical guides. I'd recommend gamedev.net for a huge resource of "how to" guides, or perhaps doing some more googling.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables) help?